# Skip special character \ from regular expression in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

From the string - code-challenge=ndh37hdjdhf\hdhjf-ybd_536\x26

I want to capture only - `ndh37hdjdhfhdhjf-ybd_536`

I tried regular expression `code-challenge=(.+?)\\26`, but it takes the character \ along with other, i dont want this character to be part of the regular expression. How i can achieve this.
Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `\` character in the resulting JMeter Variable using [__strReplace()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) function like:

```
${__strReplace(${foo},\\\\,,)}
```

__strReplace() function can be installed as a part of [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

If you cannot or not willing to use plugins the same can be achieved using JMeter's built-in [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('foo').replace('\\\'\,''),)}
```

Demo:

[image]